# Хождений по строкам в файле (C#)

Tags: c#, winforms

Есть файл "io.bin" и содержит это:

```
ID: 1
Current date and time (time UTC): 05.12.2017 12:09:26
Global time: 00:10:00

ID: 2
Current date and time (time UTC): 06.12.2017 13:04:19
Global time: 00:05:30

ID: 3
...
```

Есть код который должен найти `Current date and time (time UTC): 06.12.2017` и вывести все в textBox до следующего пробела, то-есть только это:

```
ID: 2
Current date and time (time UTC): 06.12.2017 13:04:19
Global time: 00:05:30
```

Сам код:

```
private static string getDate, setInfo = "info";    
...
private void selectDate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    getDate = dateTimePicker1.Text;

    foreach (string line in File.ReadLines("io.bin"))
    {
        if (line.Contains("Current date and time (time UTC): " + getDate))
        {
            //тут надо реализовать хождение по строкам, Но как это сделать?
        }

        StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader("io.bin");
        while (setInfo != null)
        {
            setInfo = streamReader.ReadLine();
            textBox1.Text += setInfo + " \r\n";
        }
    }
}
```

UPD: Немного не закончил свой вопрос.
Надо сделать так, чтобы эта часть кода потом подружилась с вашей реализацией

```
StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader("io.bin");
        while (setInfo != null)
        {
            setInfo = streamReader.ReadLine();
            textBox1.Text += setInfo + " \r\n";
        }
```

То есть: программа ищет по строкам с помощью `if (line.Contains("Current date and time (time UTC): " + getDate))` строку`Current date and time (time UTC): 05.12.2017` пропуская все остальные, затем берет и копирует целый блок (от пробела до пробела). И выводит в Text Box

```
ID: 2
Current date and time (time UTC): 06.12.2017 13:04:19
Global time: 00:05:30
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var massline = File.ReadAllLines("io.bin");   
for (int i = 0; i < massline.Count(); i++)
{
    var line = massline[i];

    if (line.Contains("Current date and time (time UTC): "+ getDate))
    {
        //пример "хождения" по строкам
        Console.WriteLine(massline[i-1]);
        Console.WriteLine(massline[i]);
        Console.WriteLine(massline[i+1]);
    }
}
```

С учетом upd:

```
var massline = File.ReadAllLines("io.bin");   
for (int i = 0; i < massline.Count(); i++)
{
    var line = massline[i];

    if (line.Contains("Current date and time (time UTC): "+ getDate))
        textBox1.Text +=massline[i-1] + " \r\n" +massline[i]  + " \r\n"+ massline[i+1];


}
```

Comment: `string[] massline = File.ReadLines("io.bin");`
Не удается неявно преобразовать тип "System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string>" в "string[]". Существует явное преобразование (возможно, пропущено приведение типов).

Comment: А если сделать так: `string[] massline = (string[]) File.ReadLines("io.bin");` то, Не удалось привести тип объекта "System.IO.ReadLinesIterator" к типу "System.String[]".

Comment: `File.ReadLines("io.bin").ToArray();`

Comment: аа, ну да, я писал сразу сюда и не потестил, видимо, возвращает коллекцию, по этому используй `var` вместо `string[]`, ну, или `List<string>` тож должно работать

Comment: это `File.ReadLines("io.bin").ToArray()` материализует коллекцию и заставит код занести весь файл в память. Чем оно будет отличаться от `File.ReadAllLines("io.bin")`?

Comment: Добавил UPD. Пересмотрите вопрос.

Comment: @Lolidze Только там все таки `var massline = File.ReadLines("io.bin").ToArray();`
А так огромное спасибо)

Comment: @MiT чтобы не морочиться с этой конструкцией `File.ReadLines("io.bin").ToArray();`, замените её на `File.ReadAllLines("io.bin");`

Answer (score 3):

Как вариант с использованием LINQ

```
var file = @"......";
var pattern = "Current date and time (time UTC): 06.12.2017 13:04:19";  

var lines = File.ReadLines(file) // Начинаем читать файл построчно
    .SkipWhile(line => !line.Contains(pattern)) // пропускаем все строки до совпадения с паттерном
    .Skip(1) // пропускаем строку Current date and time (time UTC): 06.12.2017 13:04:19
    .TakeWhile(line => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(line)) // Считывем все строки от паттерна до первой пустой строки
    .ToArray(); // материализуем коллекцию
```

UPD. Сложить массив строк в одну строку с сепаратором можно так:

```
textBox1.Text += String.Join(Environment.NewLine, lines);
```

Comment: я не думаю, что ТС разберется в linq выражениях, когда не работал даж с массивами, но пример хороший +

Comment: @Lolidze я потому и прокомментировал каждую строчку :)

Comment: А как это "чудо" вывести в TextBox?
С массивами работал, нужен альтернативный вариант.

Comment: @MiT ну раз работали, то `lines` как раз и является массивом, запишите его содержимое в текстбокс ( используйте цикл )

Comment: @Lolidze Спасибо за пояснение, но я думаю мне рано LINQ изучать)